# Custom space tokenization with Spacy

Tags: python, spacy

Spacy tokenizer's behavior is to squash single spaces into previous token's `whitespace` property and more than two consecutive spaces are merged to form single separate token. A single space at start of a sentence also forms a single token. These space only tokens have `pos_` as `SPACE`.

I want a way to modify this behavior so that even consecutive spaces are added to the `whitespace` property of the previous token instead of forming a separate token.

Example:

**sentence**          ' Is this  working properly.'

Current behaviour of the tokenizer -

**sentence.tokens**               : [' ', 'Is', 'this', '  ', 'working', 'properly', '.']

**token.whitespace** : ['', ' ', ' ', '', ' ', '', ''] *(either 0 or 1 spaces)*

Expected custom behaviour of the tokenizer -

**sentence.tokens**               : [' ', 'Is', 'this', 'working', 'properly', '.'] (first space can't be avoided)

**token.whitespace** : ['', ' ', '  ', ' ', '', ''] (0 or more spaces)

I can do this with a loop after tokenization and setting a new `._.whitespaces` custom spacy property for each token. But this would involve converting the doc object to list of tokens which I want to avoid because the doc object provides some nice properties over all tokens. If I were to construct new doc object with tokens without spaces using `tokenizer.tokens_from_list`, I won't get proper POS tags for the tokens since the word's text would contain spaces.